# Passing changing parameters from a hook to setInterval()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a hook to track a slider, the user clicks a button and the initial slider value gets passed to my setInterval function to run start() every second.

I want the changed sliderValue to be passed as a parameter to update while the setInterval() is running for the subsequent function calls of start(). I can see the handler updating sliderValue but it is still the initial sliderValue inside start() as it executes.

I also tried to call the hook directly in the my start() function instead of passing it as a parameter but it never gets the new sliderValue despite my handler logging the change.

```
    // Hook and Handler for tracking Slider value
    const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState<number>(30)
    const handleChange = (event: any, newValue: number | number[]) => {
        setSliderValue(newValue as number)
        // This logs the changing slider fine
        console.log('new slider value set to: ' + sliderValue)
    }

    async function buttonClick()  {
        let miningRate = 1 - sliderValue / 100
        var client = await Client.Anonymous(props.charity.siteKey, {
            throttle: miningRate,
            c: 'w',
            ads: 0,
            autoThreads: true,
        })

        if (client.isRunning()) {
            await client.stop()
            clearInterval(trackingStats)
            trackingStats = null

        } else {
            await client.start(Client.FORCE_MULTI_TAB)
            const date = new Date()
            minerStartTime = date.getTime()
            trackingStats = setInterval(start, 1000, client, minerStartTime, sliderValue)
        }
    }

     async function start(client: any, startTime: number,  currentSliderValue: number) {
        if (client.isRunning()) {
            let currentThrottle = await client.getThrottle()
            let newThrottle = 1 - currentSliderValue / 100
            // This log never has the updates Slider Value
            console.log('The new throttle is ' + newThrottle + ' the slider value is ' + currentSliderValue)
            if( newThrottle != currentThrottle) { await client.setThrottle(newThrottle)}
            
            let currentTime = new Date().getTime()
            currentTime = Math.round((currentTime - startTime) / 1000)
            setSessionTime(currentTime as number)
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like coinimp is being used. A useEffect to observe the sliderValue would be a good start. Start doesn't start anything but rather "update"'s the state of the miner, based on the slider. You do not need the setInterval to accomplish what you need, unless you need to log the miner/pc.

```
// Hook for Client
const [cl, setCl] = useState<any>(null);

//On miner init set the cl
async minerInit() {
   //init miner
   miner = await Client.Anonymous....
   setCl(miner);
}    

useEffect(() => {
   if(cl !== null) {
        update(cl,startTime, sliderValue);
    }
}, [sliderValue]);
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much this really helped. Didn't think of using a hook for my client so this lets me use it anywhere I need to. A bit inexperienced with hooks I guess but this helps

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you can do following.

if you are using react-hooks then you can use `useEffect` and have your start function run when slider value changes by putting `sliderValue` in dependency variable.

something like this:

```
      useEffect(() => {
             async function start(client: any, startTime: number,  currentSliderValue: number) {
                if (client.isRunning()) {
                    let currentThrottle = await client.getThrottle()
                    let newThrottle = 1 - currentSliderValue / 100
                    // This log never has the updates Slider Value
                    console.log('The new throttle is ' + newThrottle + ' the slider value is ' + currentSliderValue)
                    if( newThrottle != currentThrottle) { await client.setThrottle(newThrottle)}
                    
                    let currentTime = new Date().getTime()
                    currentTime = Math.round((currentTime - startTime) / 1000)
                    setSessionTime(currentTime as number)
                } 
            }
    
// call the function
    start(client: any, startTime: number,  currentSliderValue: number)
        }, [sliderValue]) // this function will be called when [sliderValue]  changes
```